# How to build dense trajectory without sudoers permission

Tags: linux, opencv, machine-learning, ffmpeg

I'm stuck for a week trying to install iDT(https://github.com/chuckcho/iDT) in a server hosted by university in which I don't have root permissions. (VERSION=12.04.5 LTS)

I tried to install the 2 main libraries (opencv and ffmpeg) following part(different versions) of this tutorial: http://dridini.blogspot.com/

I managed (I think) to install the libraries in local:

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-93084-g835ab35 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
configuration: --prefix=/home/XXXXX/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/XXXXX/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/XXXXX/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/XXXXX/bin --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-pic --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
libavcodec     58. 46.100 / 58. 46.100
libavformat    58. 26.100 / 58. 26.100
libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100 

pkg-config --modversion opencv
2.4.13.5
```

I exported the LD_LIBRARY_PATH where all .so are.(I cannot perform ldconfig after)
But when I try to make this is the result:

```
g++ -L/home/chuck/opencv-2.4.11-cuda7.5/lib -L/opt/lib -pipe -Wall -O3 -ggdb -o release/DenseTrackStab  -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_ocl -lavformat -lavdevice -lavutil -lavcodec -lswscale
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_video
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_calib3d
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_features2d
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_nonfree
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ocl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavformat
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavdevice
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavutil
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavcodec
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lswscale
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [release/DenseTrackStab] Error 1
```

I tried to modify the makeFile in order to add there the path or typing make with ldflag ( make "LDFLAGS=-L/$HOME/lib/opencv-2.4.13.5/lib/ -L/$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib") giving me the same result:

```
g++ -L/home/XXXXX/opencv-2.4.13.5/release/lib -L/opt/lib -pipe -Wall -O3 -ggdb -o release/DenseTrackStab  -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_ocl -lavformat -lavdevice -lavutil -lavcodec -lswscale
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 10
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 10
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 2
```

This is the original Makefile

```
# custom opencv
OPENCV_INC := /home/chuck/opencv-2.4.11-cuda7.5/include
OPENCV_LIB := /home/chuck/opencv-2.4.11-cuda7.5/lib

# set the binaries that have to be built
TARGETS := DenseTrackStab Video

# set the build configuration set 
BUILD := release
#BUILD := debug

# set bin and build dirs
BUILDDIR := .build_$(BUILD)
BINDIR := $(BUILD)

# libraries 
LDLIBS = $(addprefix -l, $(LIBS) $(LIBS_$(notdir $*)))
LIBS := \
    opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_video opencv_imgproc opencv_calib3d opencv_features2d opencv_nonfree \
    opencv_ocl \
    avformat avdevice avutil avcodec swscale

# set some flags and compiler/linker specific commands
CXXFLAGS = -pipe -D __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D STD=std -Wall $(CXXFLAGS_$(BUILD)) -I. -I$(OPENCV_INC) -I/opt/include
CXXFLAGS_debug := -ggdb
CXXFLAGS_release := -O3 -DNDEBUG -ggdb
LDFLAGS = -L$(OPENCV_LIB) -L/opt/lib -pipe -Wall $(LDFLAGS_$(BUILD))
LDFLAGS_debug := -ggdb
LDFLAGS_release := -O3 -ggdb

include make/generic.mk
```

Is it possible what I'm trying to do or I must give up? Any better solution for using this software?
thank you